# Only allow Google and Bing bots to crawl a site

Tags: web-crawlers, robots.txt

I am using following robots.txt file for a site: Target is to allow googlebot and bingbot to access the site except the page `/bedven/bedrijf/*` and block all other bots from crawling the site.

```
User-agent: googlebot
Disallow: /bedven/bedrijf/*
Crawl-delay: 10

User-agent: google
Disallow: /bedven/bedrijf/*
Crawl-delay: 10

User-agent: bingbot
Disallow: /bedven/bedrijf/*
Crawl-delay: 10

User-agent: bing
Disallow: /bedven/bedrijf/*
Crawl-delay: 10

User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Does the last rule `User-agent: * Disallow: /` disallow all bots from crawling every pages on the site?

Comment: This whole task concerns me. There are other search engines, and anyone who uses them won't see your site. http://theeword.co.uk/info/search_engine_market/ says that 4.99% of the internet is not on your search engines. That's *a lot* of people. A better method would be to monitor your traffic and see if any bot actually causes issues, then block those specifically.

Comment: A misbehaving bot could just totally ignore your `robots.txt` anyways

Comment: Really bad bots don't care about robots.txt

Comment: @NickT, in the real world, there are no shortage of poorly-behaved bots that follow `robots.txt`, or at least the `Disallow: /` rule.  If your personal website is getting hammered into the ground because a bot programmer never considered that the server might be a Raspberry Pi on the wrong end of a 256 kbit connection, a blanket exclusion like this is useful.

Comment: @GKFX I agree with you. But currently we are only allowing google and bing bot.

Comment: @Console _why?_

Comment: Isn't this a risky move? IIRC, Google isn't that happy with sites that try to show different content to different visitors.

Comment: @MSalters Google [approves of using robots.txt, even with specific rules for Googlebot](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062596?hl=en&ref_topic=6061961)   Doing so is not considered "cloaking" or in any dangerous from an SEO standpoint.

Comment: @Console if a client asks something stupid, your job is to have him change idea

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The last record (started by `User-agent: *`) will be followed by all polite bots that don’t identify themselves as "googlebot", "google", "bingbot" or "bing".
And yes, it means that they are not allowed to crawl anything.

You might want to omit the `*` in `/bedven/bedrijf/*`.
In the original robots.txt specification, `*` has no special meaning, it’s just a character like any other. So it would only disallow crawling of pages that literally have the character `*` in their URL.
While Google doesn’t follow the robots.txt specification in that regard, because they use `*` as a wildcard for "any sequence of characters", it’s [not needed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22156788/1591669) for them in this case: `/bedven/bedrijf/*` and `/bedven/bedrijf/` would mean exactly the same: block all URLs whose path **begins** with `/bedven/bedrijf/`.

And finally, you could reduce your robots.txt to two records, because a record can have [multiple `User-agent` lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20307057/1591669):

```
User-agent: googlebot
User-agent: google
User-agent: bingbot
User-agent: bing
Disallow: /bedven/bedrijf/
Crawl-delay: 10

User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Comment: Note that *Google ignores the crawl-delay directive* in robots.txt. You have to set it in Google Webmaster Tools instead.

Comment: User-agents are case sensitive so this will actually block Google which uses `Googlebot`

Comment: @gaefan: The robots.txt spec doesn’t say that the User-agent values are case-sensitive. Instead it recommends: "The robot should be liberal in interpreting this field. A case insensitive substring match of the name without version information is recommended." -- Could be the case that Google doesn’t follow this recommendation, but that would surprise me.

Answer (score -3):

Bots, especially bad ones, may ignore robots.txt file. So no matter what is written there some bots may crawl your site.